# Why doesn't adding an index to a Realm Object speed up my count query?

Tags: swift, indexing, realm

I have the following code I'm using to try to test indexing with Realm.  I have an object class with a single Int value that is indexed, also an identical class, but unindexed.
After inserting 1 million rows of each class, with evenly distributed values, I run some queries to see the time it takes with and without indexes.

The time is basically the same (sometimes unindexed will be slightly faster, sometimes indexed will be slightly faster -- but within about 5% or something).

the results I get are these:

```
realm init6 took: 79.721125 ms
1000000
baseCountIndexed took: 0.233 ms
1000000
baseCountUnindexed took: 0.075833 ms
500000
getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString took: 18.982542 ms
500000
getCountIndexedObjsViaWhereClosure took: 16.156041 ms
500000
getCountUnindexedObjsViaFilterString took: 17.985084 ms
500000
getCountUnindexedObjsViaWhereClosure took: 16.031917 ms
```

I would expect the indexed version to be faster -- seems like it should be close to the base count time, since an index should result in O(Log N) time -- the indexed version should at least be faster than unindexed.

What am I doing wrong?

The code I'm using follows: (long so I could make it complete / runnable)

The code basically inserts 1 million indexed objects, and 1 million unindexed objects, then gets the count of both types -- which is very fast -- and then does 2 different kinds of where clauses, one using a .filter(String), and one using a .where closure, to select 1/2 the objects, then do a count.

It is my understanding that the results coming from realm are lazy, and so the count should be done without loading the objects into memory.

The times for all 4 queries (indexed with .filter and indexed with .where, and unindexed for .filter & .where) all take about the same amount of time.

Edit:
After the answer from [jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851937/jay) below, I ran the same code, with results not massively dissimilar -- I got about 33% speed increase by indexing, rather than the 66% he got.  Still I would expect the results to be near instant for an indexed field, so something isn't right.  I'll update if / when I figure it out.  For now I'm moving on, since even the unindexed speed is good enough for my current usage.  This is just really weird to see it so slow with indexes.

```
import RealmSwift
class TimeIt {
  let val = DispatchTime.now()
  func elapsed() -> DispatchTimeInterval {
    return val.distance(to: DispatchTime.now())
  }

  static func time(_ desc: String, aclosure: () -> Void) {
    let t = TimeIt()
    aclosure()
      print("\(desc) took: \(Double(t.elapsed().nanoseconds) / 1000000.0) ms")
  }
}

class RealmIndexed: Object {
  @Persisted var id = UUID().uuidString
  @Persisted(indexed: true) var val: Int = 0
}

class RealmUnindexed: Object {
  @Persisted var id = UUID().uuidString
  @Persisted var val: Int = 0
}

func generateObjs(_ hundredsOfThousands: Int = 1) {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  var objs: [RealmIndexed] = []
  for _ in 0..<hundredsOfThousands {
    for i in 0..<100_000 {
      let obj = RealmIndexed()
      obj.val = i
      objs.append(obj)
    }
  }
  try! realm.write {
    realm.add(objs)
  }
  var objs2: [RealmUnindexed] = []
  for _ in 0..<hundredsOfThousands {
    for i in 0..<100_000 {
      let obj = RealmUnindexed()
      obj.val = i
      objs2.append(obj)
    }
  }
  try! realm.write {
    realm.add(objs2)
  }
}

func baseCountIndexed() -> Int {
  return (try! Realm().objects(RealmIndexed.self)).count
}

func baseCountUnindexed() -> Int {
  return (try! Realm().objects(RealmUnindexed.self)).count
}

func getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString(_ minVal: Int = 50000) -> Int {
  let count = (try! Realm().objects(RealmIndexed.self).filter("val >= %@", minVal)).count
  return count
}

func getCountUnindexedObjsViaFilterString(_ minVal: Int = 50000) -> Int {
  let count = (try! Realm().objects(RealmUnindexed.self).filter("val >= %@", minVal)).count
  return count
}

func getCountIndexedObjsViaWhereClosure(_ minVal: Int = 50000) -> Int {
  let count = (try! Realm().objects(RealmIndexed.self).where { $0.val >= minVal }).count
  return count
}

func getCountUnindexedObjsViaWhereClosure(_ minVal: Int = 50000) -> Int {
  let count = (try! Realm().objects(RealmUnindexed.self).where { $0.val >= minVal }).count
  return count
}

func testRealmSpeed() {
  TimeIt.time("realm init6") { _ = try! Realm() }
  TimeIt.time("baseCountIndexed") { print(baseCountIndexed()) }
  TimeIt.time("baseCountUnindexed") { print(baseCountUnindexed()) }
  TimeIt.time("getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString") { print(getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString()) }
  TimeIt.time("getCountIndexedObjsViaWhereClosure") { print(getCountIndexedObjsViaWhereClosure()) }
  TimeIt.time("getCountUnindexedObjsViaFilterString") { print(getCountUnindexedObjsViaFilterString()) }
  TimeIt.time("getCountUnindexedObjsViaWhereClosure") { print(getCountUnindexedObjsViaWhereClosure()) }
}

generateObjs(10)
testRealmSpeed()
```

Comment: I threw out an answer with my testing and more data. You may have a typo in your code.. I think... The question states - *and one using a .where closure, to select 1/2 the objects* - it appears you're inserting 1M objects but the query is for >50,000, not 500,000 (so it's not 1/2). I see this function called `print(getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString())` which passes no value so that function then uses the default `func getCountIndexedObjsViaFilterString(_ minVal: Int = 50000)` and `$0.val >= minVal`. So maybe that's throwing off the tests? Let me know if I am reading it incorrectly.

Comment: You're reading it mostly correctly, but the code actually inserts values from 0 to 99999 -- 10 times -- so there are a million objects, but the 50000 query does return half of them.  Hopefully that makes sense.  It occurred to me that maybe having a perfectly even distribution across the range might end up causing a worst case scenario with the indexing, where it's very inefficient.  I'll try replicating your example, and mess around a bit with different distributions and see how they affect performance.  Thanks much for your input, I'll edit my question and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer but perhaps additional info.

I don't think you're doing anything wrong but perhaps a simpler test will be more revealing. I set up two similar objects, one using indexing on a `val` property and one not. Testing for equality; val == 5, here's the setup:

For brevity, I'm omitting the writing code but it creates 1 Million of each object containing the values 5 and 9 e.g. Realm will contain a million indexed 5,9, 5,9, 5,9 etc and a million not indexed 5,9, 5,9 etc. (5 & 9 are just arbitrary numbers I picked)

And then a function to test each object type. I queried for '5' so it would return a 1/2 million results

```
func testNotIndexed() {
    Task {
        let realm = Realm()
        let startTime = Date()
        let results = try await realm.objects(NotIndexedClass.self).where { $0.val == 5 }
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        print("Not Indexed took: \(elapsed * 1000) ms")
    }
}

func testIndexed() {
    Task {
        let realm = Realm()
        let startTime = Date()
        let results = try await realm.objects(IndexedClass.self).where { $0.val == 5 }
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
        print("Indexed took:     \(elapsed * 1000) ms")
    }
}
```

and the repeatable results

```
Not Indexed took: 1.2680292129516602 ms
Indexed took:     0.44596195220947266 ms
```

So the indexed query took roughly 1/3 the time.

If the test parameters are changed to be objects containing numbers from 0 to 999,999, and then query for all numbers > 50,000 (not 500k to increase the returned dataset size), the results are similar.

Comment: I updated my post with some further results.  I'm curious what hardware / realm versions are you running on?  You are getting much better times than me, and my version of realm doesn't have an async .objects call -- which would be nice (the let results lines gave me a warning that there was no async operation in the expression)

Comment: @KemMason I am running macOS hence the need for the `Task {}` clause, Xcode 13.4.1, and Realm SDK 10.29. Realm [10.25](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases/tag/v10.25.0) and above supports `async/await` calls and there is "some" mention about that in the documentation. Hardware is a 2019 27" iMac i9, and sometimes an iMac M1. And other times a MBP 16" M1 Max. Depends on where I am.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll have to play around a bit more with concurrency and realm :)